# How to replace Symfony2's CsrfProvider with another service?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, csrf

Symfony2's default SessionCsrfProvider can be replaced with another service that implements [CsrfProviderInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/CsrfProviderInterface.html). However, the documentation does not tell where to define the replacing service id.

The [default framework configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#full-default-configuration) allows only to set field_name and enabled/disabled flag. There is no similar configuration option as "storage_id" in sessions.

So, how to replace the default CSRF Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your config.yml

```
services:
    form.csrf_provider: 
        class: YourNamespace\YourProvider
        arguments: [ @session, %kernel.secret% ]
```